# como evitar que se muestre dos veces?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un sistema de usuarios en el que envío una solicitud(quien envía) para que que el otro usuario(quien recibe) la responda.Bien.Cuando hago el envío el botón que decía "Agregar" cambia a "Solicitud enviada".El problema esta en que cuando ingreso al perfil o mejor dicho ingreso con la cuenta del usuario al que envío la solicitud y busco mediante el buscador al usuario que me envió la solicitud el botón dice lo mismo,osea,"solicitud enviada".Como hago para que el botón me diga "Aceptar solicitud".El botón lo imprimo con un 'echo'. No se que mas hacer.Estoy algo limitado en PHP.

**Tabla personas(usuarios)**

```
   -------  --------   -----------     ---------      --------   -------
   Id        Nombre     Apellidos      Correo      Password    Foto
   --------   ---------   ---------      --------    --------    -------
   5          Luis       Tavarez          @          ****      .jpg
   6          Jose       Martinez         @          ****      .jpg
```

**Tabla relación/amigos**

```
       ------------  --------   -----------     --------
          Id        User_one    User_two        Activo
        ----------   ---------   ---------      --------
           1            5          6               0
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

 include_once('conexion.php');

 if ($user != $my_id) {

 $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registros");
 $quer = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (User_one =  
'$my_id'  AND User_two = '$user') OR (User_one = '$user' AND User_two =
 '$my_id')");

   if (mysqli_num_rows($quer) > 0) 

     {

          while ($nada = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quer)) {

             if ($nada['Activo'] == 1) {


             $mensaje = "<div class='dropdownx'><button type='button' 
             onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtnx'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-
             o-up' aria-hidden='true'></i>Amigos<i class='fa fa-caret-down' 
             aria-hidden='true'></i></button><div id='myDropdownx' 
             class='dropdowncontentx'>
             <a href='#'>Dejar de ser amigos.</a>
             <a href='#about'>About</a>

             </div></div>";

        }




              elseif ($nada['Activo'] == 0)
               {

              $mensaje = "<div class='dropdownx'><button type='button' 
              onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtnx'>Solicitud enviada<i 
              class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true'></i></button><div
              id='myDropdownx' class='dropdowncontentx'>
             <a href='#'>Cancelar Solicitud</a>
              <a href='#about'>About</a>

            </div></div>";
        }


       }

       }




    else { // if the relationship don't exist

        $mensaje = "<div class='dropdownx'><button type='button' 
        onclick='guardar(".$user.")' class='dropbtnx'><i class=' fa fa-plus'
          aria-hidden='true'></i>Agregar</button></div>";
         }






      }


     ?>
```

Comment: y donde esta el botón: *Aceptar solicitud* ?

Comment: @aldanux En el mismo perfil del usuario al que envio la solicitud

Comment: @aldanux pero tambien lo tengo en otra pagina llamada notificaciones donde me salen todas las notificaciones.

Comment: Hola @luis es un poco confuso, que condiciona que el boton diga "Aceptar solicitud"?

Comment: @sioesi.Ok.Cuando entro al perfil del usuario que quiero mandar la solicitud presiono el boton agregar me pone un 0 en el campo "activo".Entonces ahi es cuando condiciono para que con ese valor me diga que eso es una solicitud

Comment: Podrías colocar la estructura de tu tabla por favor? y la de los usuarios, imagino que tienes funciones de sesiones, también puedes colcoar donde validas eso? con esa info puedo darte una respuesta.

Comment: @J.Correa He editado la pregunta y he puesto las tablas.Y si,uso sesiones.Uso el id del usuario logueado y lo mantengo en una variable llamada ""$my_id"" y tengo guardado el ID del usuario al que visito su perfil en una variable llamada "$user".

Answer (score 1):

La clave está en el elseif

```
// No relación aun, pero yo soy user_one
elseif ($nada['Activo'] == 0 and $nada['user_one'] == $my_id){

   // Muestro boton aceptar solicitud si yo soy quien recibe}

} elseif ($nada['Activo'] == 0 and $nada['user_one'] == $my_id){

   // Muestro boton de solicitud enviada

}
```

Explico: Si user_one es quien envía la solicitud, sólo valida si en la sesión eres user_one y en caso de ser así seguir mostrando "solicitud enviada";

pero si user_one es quien recibe la solicitud, colocas el "Aceptar solicitud".

Si no me di a entender por favor comenta.

**Nota:** podrías dividir el código y crear una función que sirva para identificar al usuario si es user_one o user_two.

Comment: Ok.tratare de hacerlo despues.pues acabo de hacerlo un poco mas sencillo,implementando Seguir y dejar de seguir ,asi como twitter..Pero cuando tome lo que me dijiste volvere a ti si tengo inconvenientes.Y marcare como respuesta

Comment: Ok, me parece bien